# [Oracle/PHP]Is it possible to pass an array to a PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: php, oracle, arrays, plsql, procedure

If it is possible, how does the parameter need to look like in the procedure?
And how do you pass an array to a procedure?

Comment: Is this for Oracle or Postgres?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yep, you can. You need to use oci_bind_array_by_name.

[This page](http://www.navioo.com/php/tutorials/Array_Binding_and_PLSQL_Bulk_Processing_863.html) has a good example of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass multiple records from .NET into Oracle with just one call. You set the ArrayBindCount of the command object to the number of elements you want to pass in and the value of the parameter to the array of values rather than a single value. Sample [here](http://codenodes.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/insert-multiple-records-to-oracle-table-in-one-call/):